# Change Facebook OAuth connect image by language

Tags: social-network

now it uses fbauth.module the line

```
$src = ($GLOBALS['is_https'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://www.example.com/sites/default/files/connect_light_medium_short.gif';
```

How can I change it by language?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. Isn't the image the same for every language?

Comment: on image there's text writing Connect so i should have one image for every languge differnt text.